# how to add items in recyclerview if firestore users collection have specific collection in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, chat

As you can see in the firestore screenshot, i have two users in users collection and in one user i have engagedChatChannels collection because chat is start for one user but other don't have engagedChatChannels

I want get to all users those have engagedChatChannels,

I tried following code. I can check if user have engagedChatChannel collection or not but i am not able to add items in mutableListOf based on condition. I tried by removing condition as well but items not adding.

[image]

```
fun addUsersListener(context: Context, onListen: (List<Item>)->Unit): ListenerRegistration{
    return firestoreInstance.collection("users")
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
            if(firebaseFirestoreException !=null){
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }


            val items = mutableListOf<Item>()
            querySnapshot?.documents?.forEach {


                firestoreInstance.collection("users")
                    .document(it.id).collection("engagedChatChannels").get()
                    .continueWith { result->

                        Log.v("CHATS", "Exits" + result.result?.size())
                        if(result.result!!.size() > 0)
                            items.add(
                                UserItem(
                                    it.toObject(User::class.java)!!,
                                    it.id,
                                    0,
                                    context
                                )
                            )
                    }

            }
            onListen(items)
        }
}
```

Comment: So you want to display only the users that have `engagedChatChannels` subcollection within the user document?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes but i am actually able to check that. Issue the add items on that condition. addOnCompleteListener, continueWith all works after List is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're firing the `onListen(items)` before you've actually checked the existence. Any code that depends on data from the database must be **inside** the callback that fires when that data is available.

Since you want to perform multiple checks, consider using a counter to check whether all of them completed:

```
firestoreInstance.collection("users")
    .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
        if(firebaseFirestoreException !=null){
            return@addSnapshotListener
        }

        val count = 0

        val items = mutableListOf<Item>()
        querySnapshot?.documents?.forEach {
            firestoreInstance.collection("users")
                .document(it.id).collection("engagedChatChannels").get()
                .continueWith { result->
                    if(result.result!!.size() > 0)
                        items.add(
                            UserItem(
                                it.toObject(User::class.java)!!,
                                it.id,
                                0,
                                context
                            )
                        )
                    }
                    count = count + 1
                    if (count == querySnapshot?.documents?.size) {
                        onListen(items)
                    }
                }
    }
```

Note that I didn't run the above code, so it may contain syntax errors. However I hope the flow is clear, with both the `onListen` call being inside the callback, and the counter used to check if all subcollection checks were done.

---

The above approach should work, but I'd typically take another approach. If you need to know on a user-level whether they have a certain subcollection, I'd store that fact in a field in each user-document. That way you can simply query the user documents for the ones having the correct value, and prevent this nested loop/query combination.

Comment: Thank you Frank, I got the approach. but code is not working. 
I tried to Log the counter at the end. But thing is , it logs the counter correctly and after some milisec i see Log for checking size of result in continueWith. 
So somehow still its checking condition after my counter condition

Comment: i tried to put delay as well for onListen but still its not adding item
val handler = Handler()
                val runnable = Runnable {
                    onListen(items)
                }
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000)

Comment: Adding a delay is a workaround at best, and one I'd never recommend. I rechecked my code and it looks correct, minus any syntax errors. If you set a breakpoint in the `continueWith` and run in a debugger, does it trigger when you expect it to trigger? And then when you put a breakpoint on `onListen(items)`, when does that trigger compared to the other breakpoint?